# Remote garage door opener malfunction

Tags: garage-door-opener

Wall opener opens the door but does not close it. Same issue from my car. There was a power outage recently. Does it mean the opener is damaged?

Comment: What you're calling the "opener" is just a signal generator. The _actual_ opener, containing the motor, does the work (or not). Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to add enough information about your equipment that we can help you. Power _outages_ almost never damage household equipment. If you suspect a surge, or a brownout (low voltage) situation, tell us about that up there, too.

Comment: I am confused. If you can close the door, then the motor only worked once. If you tried multiple times, then how did you close it.

Comment: Does the opener flash any sort of indications of a failure or blockage?  Need more info on what actually happens when you try and close the door.

Answer (score 1):

Open and Close use different functions.

Open for example dose not use the sensors mounted on the sides of the door, it just opens.

On the other hand the Closing uses the sensors to monitor if anything is in the way and stop the motor.

Check your door sensors alignment and function.